# Post MVC ViewModel data to controller through JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following models:

```
public class ColourCounts
{
    [Key]
    public int ColourGroup { get; set; }
    public int ColourCount { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
public class SizeCounts
{
    [Key]
    public int SizeGroup { get; set; }
    public int SizeCount { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}

public class New
{
    public New()
    {
        this.Newz = new New();
        this.Colour = new ColourCounts();
        this.ColourList = new List<ColourCounts>();
        this.Size = new SizeCounts();
        this.SizeList = new List<SizeCounts>();
    }

    public New Newz { get; set; }
    public ColourCounts Colour { get; set; }
    public List<ColourCounts> ColourList { get; set; }
    public SizeCounts Size { get; set; }
    public List<SizeCounts> SizeList { get; set; }
}
```

In my Index view I have

```
@model ...Models.New
...
    <div id="colourTable">
        @Html.Partial("_ColourCounts")
        <div class="spinner">
        </div>
        <div>Loading...</div>
    </div>

    <div id="sizeTable">
        @Html.Partial("_SizeCounts")
        <div class="spinner">
        </div>
        <div>Loading...</div>
    </div>
```

The partial view for

> _ColourCounts

&

> _SizeCounts

are

```
@model ...Models.New
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ColourList)
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

&

```
@model ...Models.New
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SizeList)
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

The editor templates are

```
@model ..Models.SizeCounts

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SizeGroup)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SizeGroup)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SizeValue)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SizeValue)
    </td>
    <td">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SizeCount)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SizeCount)
    </td>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Selected)</td>
</tr>
```

&

```
@model ..Models.ColourCounts

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ColourGroup)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ColourGroup)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ColourValue)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ColourValue)
    </td>
    <td">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ColourCount)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ColourCount)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Selected)</td>
</tr>
```

I asynchronously load these by which is on the index view

```
<script type="text/javascript" name ="Size">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //var val = $('#yearSelect3').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/News/_SizeCounts",
            type: "GET",
        })
        .done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("#sizeTable").html(partialViewResult)
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" name="Colour">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //var val = $('#yearSelect3').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/News/_ColourCounts",
            type: "GET",
        })
        .done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("#colourTable").html(partialViewResult)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Whenever a user Checks any of the checkboxes, I want to capture ALL of the values (thee Newz can be ingored as that won't be re-rendered), the checkboxes and the hidden for values  and post back to a controller

```
public ActionResult ReCalc(New model)
        {
          ....
        }
```

That then will get some new counts using a Linq query and I'll re-render the EditorTemplates in the Partial views as on the page load but with the new data.

I can't capture the form data in a way that I can pass it to the model in the ReCalc controller though.

I have tried in jquery using

```
var x = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
                var y = JSON.stringify(x);
```

while the jason is "valid" according to `http://jsonlint.com/` I get

```
{"name":"SizeList[0].Selected","value":"true"},{"name":"SizeList[0].Selected","value":"false"}
```

So clearly a problem there, and also the model is null in the controller when looking at in in debug.

Really appreciate any help to get the jquery right for this.

If you need any further information please let me know in layman's terms, I'm a T-SQL guy :) Thanks!

Comment: `$.post('@Url.Action("ReCalc")', $('#myForm').serialize(), function(response) { .... });`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working now!

I did try var x = ...serialize(); but kept getting an invalid JASON primitive error.

The only difference was I was doing something like

Comment: //$.ajax({
                //    url: "/Newz/_ReCalc",
                //    dataType: 'json',
                //    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                //    type: 'post',
                //    cache: false,
                //    data: x,

Comment: Haven't used just $.post but looked and it said it is a short hand of that, have I passed in the types or settings in my one? (for my own learning purposes)

Comment: The `$.ajax()` would have worked fine had you omitted `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that.